# wait() and notify() with linelistener

Tags: java

As this is my first post, I apologize for any mistakes it's structure. I am working on a personal project which is a clock made in java to display time/date/day and play an audio file every quarter as well as chime the hour. The GUI is built with swing items.

When the clock reaches a time it must chime/play sound, I want an icon to be displayed on the GUI while the clock is sounding. At the moment, the icon is toggled at the beginning of the method and toggled again at the end. I would like the method to **wait()** while the audio is being played before toggling the icon the second time. (Perhaps there is a better way to do this.)

I am inexperienced with java and I feel as if I'm using **wait()** and **notify()** incorrectly. I've looked at examples until my head spun, and I'm still unsure of the solution I need.

I'm using **LineListener** to notify that the **Clip** has finished playing and can proceed to toggle the icon.

This is the methods for playing the chimes:

```
public void play() throws InterruptedException {
    while (mute == false) {
        synchronized (chimeLock) {
            ChimeClockGUI.toggleChimeIcon();
            clip.start();
            do {
                chimeLock.wait();
            } while (clip.isActive());
            ChimeClockGUI.toggleChimeIcon();
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
public void toll() throws InterruptedException {
    if (mute == false) {
        synchronized (chimeLock) {
            ChimeClockGUI.toggleChimeIcon();
            ONTHEHOUR.clip.start();
            do {
                chimeLock.wait();
            } while (ONTHEHOUR.clip.isActive());
            if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) {
                clip.loop(11);
                do {
                    chimeLock.wait();
                } while (clip.isActive());
            } else if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR) == 1) {
                clip.start();
                do {
                    chimeLock.wait();
                } while (clip.isActive());
            } else {
                clip.loop(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR) - 1);
                do {
                    chimeLock.wait();
                } while (clip.isActive());
            }
            ChimeClockGUI.toggleChimeIcon();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the **update()** method from **LineListener**:

```
@Override
public void update(LineEvent le) {
    synchronized (chimeLock) {
        LineEvent.Type type = le.getType();
        if (type == LineEvent.Type.OPEN) {
            System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                    .format(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())) + ": Clip opened...");
        } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.CLOSE) {
            System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                    .format(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())) + ": Clip closed...");
            chimeLock.notifyAll();
        } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.START) {
            System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                    .format(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())) + ": Clip started...");
        } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                    .format(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())) + ": Clip stopped...");
            chimeLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm including the method that calls **play()** and **toll()**.

```
chimeService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    try {
        ChimeClockSound.TOLL.toll();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChimeClockGUI.class.getName())
                  .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Any help or suggestions would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Note `synchronized` functions blocks the current(this) object, and no any other thread could access it. If the object/class is related to your GUI stuff, it's not recommended to lock `this`, simply have an `object` instead.

Comment: In this case `play()` and `toll()` are only called from a single `ScheduledExecutor` thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue here is that `clip.isRunning()` returns `false` until the data actually begins loading, so you should make sure `wait()` is always called with a do-while loop:

```
do {
    wait();
} while (clip.isRunning());
```

It's also better to call `wait`/`notify` on a dedicated lock object rather than on the entire instance of the class. This way, other uses of `wait`/`notify` don't interfere and your methods don't need to be `synchronized`, which can slow things down.

```
private final Object chimeLock = new Object();
```

With this, you can replace `wait()` with:

```
synchronized (chimeLock) {
    chimeLock.wait();
}
```

...and replace `notifyAll()` with:

```
synchronized (chimeLock) {
    chimeLock.notifyAll();
}
```

...and remove `synchronized` from your method declarations, since it's now synchronizing on the lock object instead.

The last thing to keep in mind is that `InterruptedException` is only thrown if the thread is interrupted, which usually means something (like the JVM) wants the thread to stop running. When you catch this, you should wrap things up and return ASAP.

Comment: Thank you for your help in this. I've implemented what you've suggested, but it appears that nothing is happening when `chimeLock.notifyAll()` is being invoked.

Comment: Did you remove `synchronized` from the methods? What does your code look like now? Also, I just noticed, you need to make sure `toll` doesn't enter the do-while loop if the clip is never started in the switch block, since `update` will never be called.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect the changes. When toll is called a clip should always be played, in theory. Also, I added the method that calls `play()` and `toll()` in case I'm doing something wrong there.

Comment: I notice you're using a second clip instance `ONTHEHOUR.clip` in your `toll` method, did you add this class instance as a line listener for that clip as well? That's the only way it'll call `update`, which calls `notifyAll`.

Comment: Also note that if you want to play the same Clip instance multiple times, you need to reset it with `clip.setFramePosition(0)` before calling `start` again. This would affect the `while` loop in `play` as well as multiple calls to `toll`. It might be better to split all this out into a private method that synchronizes on the lock, plays the clip, waits on the lock, and resets the clip.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Each `clip` has a linelistener added. I know the update method is being called in all cases as it's printing "Clip stopped..." to the console. I actually discovered that the frame position must be reset on my own. While I would liked to have used a locking item, I was able to reach the desired behavior using a different solution.